# has_many_through association not inserting values in params to join table instead inserting null

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

EDIT

I am new to rails and got stuck at this step.Researched whatever I could on the internet but could not fix this. Please help!  I am using Rails 3.2.13.

This is how my models look now. Excuse me for the typo, if any, as this is a made up example. cleaned up a bit but again the same problem. Could be bug not sure.

I have 3 Models:

```
1.Cuisine (example Thai/Mexican/Italian) 

 class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :testers, :through => :ratings
 has_many :ratings, :inverse_of => :cuisine

 2.Testers

 class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :cuisines, :through => :ratings
 has_many :ratings, :inverse_of => :tester

 3.Rating (note:had the inverse_of here too but did not work)

 class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tester
 belongs_to :cuisine

 testers_controller

class TestersController < ApplicationController

 def update  ##TO DO: SAVE (tester + cuisine IDS) IN THE ratings/JOIN TABLE 
 @tester = Tester.find(params[:id]) 
 @tester.ratings.create
 render text: 'Success'
 end
```

This is form in the view. I am not using / rendering any partials for this exercise.

```
 <%= form_for :rating, url: ratings_path do |f| %>

   <h3>Review:</h3>
     <% for cuisine in Cuisine.find(:all) %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag("tester[cuisine_ids][]", cuisine.id) %>
      <%= cuisine.cuisine_name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
  <% end %>
```

The development log shows as below.

```
         Started PUT "/testers/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-27 16:53:31 -0700
 Processing by TestersController#update as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",         "authenticity_token"=>"5awCMjqwUSHaByj1XFDs5UKZUjyvMoigB88NZCFWgSE=", "tester"=>  {"cuisine_ids"=>["3", "6"]}, "commit"=>"Update Tester", "id"=>"3"}
   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `testers`.* FROM `testers` WHERE `testers`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
    Cuisine Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cuisines`.* FROM `cuisines` WHERE `cuisines`.`id` = 3 LIMIT     1
     (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `ratings` (`created_at`, `created_by`, `cuisine_id`,       `updated_at`, `tester`, `tester_id`) VALUES ('2014-11-27 23:53:31', NULL, NULL, '2014-11-27       23:53:31', NULL, 3)
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

Couple of issues here.
1. Cuisine_ids are not getting inserted in the ratings table
2. If I have combination of tester_id =1 and cuisine_ids = [2,3] already in the join table then it does nothing. I would like to insert again the same values. that is I would like to allow insert statement to work for inserting duplicate entries. That is how my ratings work.
3. If I have combination of tester_id= and cuisine_ids= [1,2,3] and if I select cuisine_ids=[2,3], then it somehow, rails deletes the cuisine_ids[1,2,3] and again inserts [2,3]. so firstly it executes
1.DELETE from ratings where tester_id=1 (and then runs the insert again)

All I want to do is to save the records which the users select using check boxes in the join table. I want to allow duplicates (for tester_id and cuisine_ids combination) in that join table. This join table might resemble to transaction tables i.e. like one product might have repeated/recurring orders by same customer. However, the entire row will still remain unique because rails has its own primary key on each table.

Let me know if you need more information. Someone please help!!!!

Thanks

Comment: One obvious problem is adding `attr_accessor`s for `cusines` in your Tester model - that needs to go or you'll never be able to assign actual "cusines".  Actually, looking at this I don't even know where to start - I think you need to go through a good Rails tutorial first.  Your `attr_accessible` statements seem to show much confusion.  You probably want to get the Rails book for Rails 3 and work through it before attempting something like this.  I will put an answer below that will clean up a lot of what you have but I fear the help will be minimal given your starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to know more about your data model but I can provide some general guidance here.

```
class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :cuisine_name, :id, :cuisine_id
 attr_accessor  :tester, :cuisine_ids
 has_many :testers, :through => :ratings
 has_many :ratings
```

First, adding ":id" to `attr_accessible` doesn't make sense.  You don't need it as it would give people the ability to update a record's id.  I'm not sure what "cuisine_id" is, it doesn't make sense that it would be in the `cuisines` table.

You definitely don't need `attr_accessor`.  And you should add inverse relationships.

So here's where we're left:

```
class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cuisine_name
  has_many :ratings, :inverse_of => :cuisine
  has_many :testers, :through => :ratings
```

Next up is Tester:

```
class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :tester_name, :id, :tester_id
 attr_accessor  :cusines
 has_many :cusines, :through => :ratings
 has_many :ratings
```

Again, your `attr_accessible` is confusing.  You also have misspelled "cuisine".  Finally, you don't need the `attr_accessor` and, again, it will actually "hide" the real "cuisines" relationship.  Here's what we end up with:

```
class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :tester_name
 has_many :ratings, :inverse_of => :tester
 has_many :cuisines, :through => :ratings
```

Finally, ratings.  This is simple and actually looks good, but it strikes me that there's probably at least some sort of "rating" attribute that should be in `attr_accessors`.  Since I don't know what's there, let's just add inverse relationships:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :tester, :inverse_of => :ratings
 belongs_to :cuisine, :inverse_of => :ratings
```

Having those correct will make fixing the rest of it possible.

Looking at your ratings controller, it's kind of confusing.  I have no idea what the "ratings" action should do.  You're mixing plurals and singulars and all that.  You have "cuisine" misspelled in another way there.  Let's start with the view:

```
 <h3>Review:</h3>
 <% for cuisine in Cuisine.find(:all) %>
   <div>
     <%= check_box_tag("tester[cuisine_ids][]", cuisine.id) %>
     <%= cuisine.cuisine_name %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
 <p><%= f.submit %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Presumably there's a "form_for" that you didn't include.  I have done the minimal needed to get this to at least render properly.  It's still not exactly what you want as it won't allow for updates.

Back to the controller, what is "ratings" supposed to do?  Is that your "new" action?

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController

 def ratings
   @ratings=Rating.new
 end
 def create
   @tester= Tester.new(params[:tester])
   params[:tester][:cuisine_ids].each do |tester|
     @cus=@tester.ratings.build(:tester_id => tester)
     @cus.save
   end
 end
```

That's a general cleanup.  You still aren't saving "@tester" or doing anything else after the create.  If you start with a general resource scaffold for `testers` you can do this pretty easily.  But with these issues fixed you can at least start making some headway.

As I said in the comment above, though, you would be wise to put this aside, go through a tutorial, and then revisit this.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.i have scenario where ,tester is rated based on the different types of cuisines he can taste. So my app has bunch of testers , who rate each other via a form having check boxes for different cuisines. For exp tester A can rate Tester B as capable of testing Thai/Chinese/Italian cuisines. The rating can be done by checking the check boxes against each cuisine for the respective tester being reviewed (tester B in this case).t works until here, but when I check the boxes&submit,insert statement inserts null in the ratings table. I am able to insert ratings from rails console.

Comment: This is how the db table looks 

id | tester_id | cuisine_id | created_by | created_at          | updated_at          | user |
+----+---------+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+

|  1 |       1 |            2 | NULL       | 2014-11-16 01:36:28 | 2014-11-16 01:36:28 | NULL |

 2 |    NULL |         NULL | NULL       | 2014-11-18 02:30:56 | 2014-11-18 02:30:56 | NULL

Comment: I think you are right and I have to bring myself up to speed with rails. Will spent the entire weekend on that rails 3 book. Thanks. I guess I should mark this answer as correct as the suggestion provided is appropriate

Comment: What you need is probably beyond the scope of a simple StackOverflow answer, but you have three tables and three models.  If I get time later I'll provide an example on github of what you need to do just to get you headed in the right direction.  Your needs are actually a little complex but I've done such many times before.

Comment: Thanks Michael, waiting eagerly for your example. Thanks

Comment: Working on it. I am trying to do from scratch but running into DB issues. Its 12AM here. Will test this tomorrow and let you know. BTW I have edited my original post so that everyone is clear on my problem.

Comment: I tried that example on github. got few errors. fixed couple of those.. still working thru. latest error 
 undefined method `tester_ids' for #<Cuisine id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: Are you using the same version of Rails that I used there along with a new (1.9.3+) version of Ruby?  The code definitely works as posted.

Comment: the code works now. However, my question is still unanswered, I need below to happen, guess it should be something simple that I am missing. If current user is Tester A , then he can search for Tester B (who is also a user of my app), check the boxes against that tester and assign those new cuisines to the Tester B. Tester B can do same for Tester A. All I want to do is to save something like this in the join table. 
        tester_id      cuisine_id
         1               3
         2               4
         2               1
         3               1
         4               2

Comment: Your question is answered as much as it's going to be on SO.  The code I provided allows you to bring up a tester, check the appropriate cuisine boxes, and then save it - at which point the join table will be populated.  You need to bring https://github.com/plataformatec/devise or https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic to handle user authentication and then build your interface for finding testers and handling the rest of it.  It will take some work, I'm just showing you the basics of how to put an application like that together.

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly if your company would like to pay for app development.

Comment: I agree. It works . I will mark this as answered as it answers most part of my question.
:) I am learning rails to make something of my own or atleast try to :). Thanks a lot for your patience. Really appreciate your help.